# New Project not being build in Visual-Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bulletphysics

What does the error in the following output means:

> ------ Build started: Project: Project_Bullett, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> Compiling...
>
> main.cpp
>
> g:\bullet-2.79\demos\ragdolldemo\ragdolldemo.h(22) : fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GlutDemoApplication.h': No such file
>   or directory
>
> RagdollDemo.cpp
>
> g:\bullet-2.79\demos\ragdolldemo\ragdolldemo.cpp(22) : fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'btBulletDynamicsCommon.h': No such
>   file or directory
>
> Generating Code...
>
> Build log was saved at "file://g:\bullet-2.79\Demos\New folder
>   (2)\Project_Bullett\Project_Bullett\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
>   Project_Bullett - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I am trying to build the existing project into new project for making change in the code so that any change wouldn't harm the original existing project but it is giving me error in output in Visual-Studio-2008-Express-Edition with using Bullet-2.79.

I also tried tutorials for adding new projects in visual studio but none helped me.

Can I get some direction, where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning** I'm not really proficient with bullet-physics so take my advises with a grain of salt. I also used VS 2012 and don't have VS 2008.

It is not clear what exactly you are doing to create your project file. The issues seems to arise from the fact that `RagdollDemo` uses files from `${BULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR}/Demos/OpenGL` and this path is not specified correctly in your project.

You may try to re-generate your project file explicitly specifying `${BULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR}` such as

```
path_to_cmake\cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 8" -DBULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR=G:/bullet-2.79
```

Assuming that you put your bullet into `G:\bullet-2.79` as it looks from your logs.

If you want to create an independent copy to start modifying it, I think that the way to do it is to copy conents of `Demos\OpenGL` and `Demos\RagdollDemo` folders to a new folder and make new `CMakeLists.txt` file mostly based on the one from `RagdollDemo` but with merged changes from `OpenGL`. Something like this (only changed parts):

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
${BULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR}/src  ${BULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR}/Extras/ConvexHull   ${BULLET_PHYSICS_SOURCE_DIR}/Glut
)

ADD_LIBRARY(OpenGLSupport
    GLDebugFont.cpp
    GLDebugFont.h
    GL_DialogDynamicsWorld.cpp
    GL_DialogDynamicsWorld.h
    GL_DialogWindow.cpp
    GL_DialogWindow.h
    GL_ShapeDrawer.cpp
    GL_ShapeDrawer.h
    GL_Simplex1to4.cpp
    GL_Simplex1to4.h
    GLDebugDrawer.cpp
    GLDebugDrawer.h

    RenderTexture.cpp
    RenderTexture.h
    DemoApplication.cpp
    DemoApplication.h

    GlutDemoApplication.cpp
    GlutDemoApplication.h
    GlutStuff.cpp
    GlutStuff.h

    stb_image.cpp
    stb_image.h

    Win32DemoApplication.cpp
    Win32DemoApplication.h
)

LINK_LIBRARIES(
OpenGLSupport  BulletDynamics  BulletCollision LinearMath    ${GLUT_glut_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}
)


ADD_EXECUTABLE(AppRagdollDemo
RagdollDemo.cpp
main.cpp
)
```

Note also that I had to modify GlutStuff.h to add a line regarding `glut.h` to other branch

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> // <-- added by me
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif //_WINDOWS
```

Hope this helps.